# SQL System Query Hanging

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

Running a query which lists all tables from all databases. However, it hangs and won't complete:

```
DECLARE @TableList TABLE (  ServerName VARCHAR(50),
                DatabaseName VARCHAR(50),
                SchemaName VARCHAR(50),
                TableName VARCHAR(50) )

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(250)
SET @SQL =
'SELECT 
    @@SERVERNAME, ''?'', s.name, t.name 
 FROM
     [?].sys.tables t 
 INNER JOIN sys.schemas s 
 ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
'

INSERT INTO @TableList
    EXEC sp_msforeachdb @SQL

SELECT * FROM @TableList
WHERE TableName LIKE '%%'
ORDER BY DatabaseName, SchemaName, TableName
```

If I change the dynamic SQL portion of the code to select the TOP 350 rows, the code completes. However anymore than that (even by 1) and the query will hang.

Any ideas?

Comment: Works perfect on my side without any change. Are you having some specific error? I had an error refering to databasename as some of our databases have longer that 50 char names. Maybe that's one of the issues you are having.

Comment: On Servers with a smaller quantity of tables the script runs fine, its only when it returns more than about 7000 tables. There's no error, it just hangs as if in an infinite loop

Comment: Hmmm...I've no other idea on what  could be happening, maybe a lock/block issue? Consider moving the question to the [dba.stackexchange.com site](http://dba.stackexchange.com/). Voted to close it and move to the dba site, I think you may get some more answers there.

Comment: Just found out one of the databases on the server belongs to a third party, So its probably a lock like you said. Altered to the dynamic SQL to have 'IF ''?'' NOT LIKE (''%THIRDPARTYNAME%'') and the query runs fine. If you make your comment into an answer i'll mark it as correct

Comment: Glad it helped. Retracted the close vote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works perfect on my side without any change. Are you having some specific error? I had an error refering to databasename as some of our databases have longer that 50 char names. Maybe that's one of the issues you are having.

Maybe a lock/block issue?